# Why we need HTTPS when we send result to user

Tags: performance, security, networking, https

**The reason we need HTTPS(Secured/Encrypted Data over network):**

- We need to get the user side data(Either via form or by URL which ever way users sends their data to server via network) securely Which is done by http + ssl encryption  - so in that case only the form or which ever URL that user posting/sending data to server has to be secure URL and not the page that I am sending to browser[ Eg. When I need to have customer register form From server itself I have to send it as https url - if I dont do that then browser will give warning like mixed content error. Instead is it wrong that browsers could have had some sort of param to mention the form I have has to be secure url.
- In some cases my server side content cant be read by anyone outside other than who I allow to be - for that I can use https to deliver the content with extra security measurements in server side.

Other than these two scenarios I dont see any reason on having https based encoded content over network. Lets assume a site with 10+ css, 10+ js, 50+ images with 200k of content weight and total weight may be ~2 - 3MB - so this whole content is encrypted - have no doubt this is going to be min. of 100 - 280 connection creation between browser and server.

Please explain - why we need to follow the way we deliver[Most of us doing because browsers/google like search engines/w3o standards asks us to use on every page].

Comment: This kind of question is better asked at security.stackexchange.com. And I recommend you to get much faster to the point when explaining your problem. Don't expect anybody to read all this just to find the actual problem you have but describe it short and clearly within the first few sentences.

Comment: You've defined your way into this problem. You've asserted without proof that responses only need to be encrypted for access control reasons. It's up to you to establish the truth of that proposition,mint for everybody else to justify universal practice.

Comment: @EJP though its upto the developer team to decide this still its industry best practice to know why we do the way this whole flow is being done. So only asked the question here. Thanks for updating question short.

Comment: @Ela I don't understand the first sentence. If you think there is some magical security theorem that says that the response to a secure request needn't be secure, let's hear what it is. Let's also hear what your plan is for implementing it.

Comment: @EJP :( I didnt had clear idea on how this system works completely and was trying to understand the need of https everywhere(where I had content generation time completely too high over normal http - since its the way caching worked in server with caching tool(varnish) which is what I should have researched more to fix).

Comment: Look at it another way. The request and response are delivered over the same connection. If that is a TLS connection, it already exists, and it's secure in both directions. Sending the response securely isn't much of an overhead, and sending it as plaintext would be extra work, even if you could identify a reason to do it, which you haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why we need to follow the way we deliver

Because otherwise it's not secure. The browsers which warn about this are not wrong.

> Let's assume a site with 10+ css, 10+ js

Just 1 .js served over non-HTTPS and a man-in-the-middle attacker could inject abitrary code into your HTTPS page, from which origin they can completely control the user's interaction with your site. That's why browsers don't allow it, and give you the mixed content warning.

(And .css can have the same impact in many cases.)

Plus it's just plain bad security-usability to switch between HTTP and HTTPS for different pages. The user is likely to fail to notice the switch, and may be tricked into entering data into (or accepting data from) a non-HTTPS page. All the attacker would have to do would be to change one of the HTTP links so it pointed to HTTP instead of HTTPS, and the usual process would be subverted.

> have no doubt this is going to be min. of 100 - 280 connection creation between browser and server.

HTTP[S] reuses connections. You don't pay the SSL handshake latency for every resource linked.

HTTPS is really not that expensive today to be worth worrying about performance for a typical small web app.

Comment: yeah I got the need of having https every where - also researched more on the same topic over and over again to understand the full process - had a concern that this was affecting the site performance and it is all again depends on server side caching setup for https which I have to do better. Thank you for your answer